# How to solve this recurrence relation with a summation in it?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How would one go about solving this recurrence relation: $T(n)$=$\sum_{i=1}^{k}T(n - d_i)$ ?

For this recurrence relation, $k$ is the number of coin denominations, and $d_i$ is the specific coin denomination. I have stared at this for a while and have no idea how to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: Well, it is a linear recurrence. For example if there were just 3 coin denominations $1,2,5$ we would have $T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+T(n-5)$. So you can solve it in the usual way, although it is likely to be messy for anything except small $k$ and $d_i$.

Comment: Well okay, I am still fairly new to the realm of recurrence relations. How exactly would you solve that one? (For  $1,2,5$)

Comment: Search this site for linear recurrence relations or look up recurrence relation in Wikipedia. But for coin problems it is usually best to use generating functions.

Comment: What would the termination or base cases for a recurrence relation like that be?